# Focusing a question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed, needs-more-focus

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Is there a function that can pivot a table like I need without an aggregation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883789/is-there-a-function-that-can-pivot-a-table-like-i-need-without-an-aggregation)

How could I reword this to be more "focused"?

Comment: My 2cts, but the "*like I need*" in the Title is completely [vague/fluff/useless/non-descriptive/ **unfocused** ] to me... // Perfect are the Input + Output, and nicely formatted, that's very good...! // No Query/Code posted, => feels a bit like "Gimme ze Codez" apart from mentioning "PIVOT" + "Aggregation" and those 2 Terms could use some Links to some Documentation or to some Thread(s) on SO showing your Research and your Attempt(s) to solve your Issue yourself...

Comment: 2cts = [two cents](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/two_cents#Noun)

Comment: And vandalizing your [Thread/Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73883789/3799241) won't help as your Edit will be rolled back...

Comment: @chivracq Lol this site is so confusing. Dont like "unfocused" questions... Continues to rollback to unfocused question.

Comment: I don't see what's confusing about the community undoing vandalism, @Patzerfaust . Of course we don't want vandalism on the site, and of course we're going to undo any we find; that's good curation. When you post *anything* here you licence it under CC-BY-SA and vandalising that content is only harmful to the content you contributed to the site, so the community restores the content.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

From what I gather my question just was to elementary for stackoverflow and I should take my questions somewhere more tailored toward beginners. Thanks all.

Comment: This isn't the right conclusion; there is a separate closure reason for that, closed as duplicate.

Comment: Your Comment now sounds funny @Larnu, after OP's "slight Edit", ah-ah...! (Check the Timeline if that Edit got rolled back...)

Comment: @chivracq or it sounded funny because it was not helpful in any way and completely contradicts their previous comment.

Comment: The OP is still making the wrong conclusion though, @chivracq . "Your question is too elementary" isn't a closure reason. It might result in downvotes from users, as many "elementary" questions also fail to demonstrate evidence of research but downvotes and closure votes have different reasons with only some overlap.

Answer (score -3):

The question looks appropriately focused to me.

Based on the content of the question (mentioning the specific function shown in the answer you received) and the answer (basically just showing how to use that function), it seems as if you understood the necessary technique and were simply not thinking clearly about how to apply it (or perhaps you misunderstood something about what "aggregation" entails, in context). If I were a SME, I might have voted to close as typo/not reproducible instead. That isn't an especially good fit, either, but my view - which seems to be commonly shared - is that it isn't the purpose of Stack Overflow Q&A to show how to apply tools to the asker's specific situation, if it follows naturally from a proper understanding of what the tool does.

Better yet: If there is a canonical along the lines of "Q. How do I {do what `PIVOT` does}? A. Use `PIVOT` {cite documentation to show what it can do}", then a question like yours could be a duplicate of that. However, there seems to be a pretty strong bias against questions like that on the site, too - despite that they are not only explicitly on topic, but often among the highest quality and most useful questions the site can offer.

Comment: Honestly, how to pivot is SQL Server is a pretty common question, and we do have several duplicate candidates for it. For the OP, where they want to pivot on the row number, one such example is [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns), where I demonstrate both a static and dynamic version. A search of "[how to pivot without aggregation in SQL Server](//google.co.uk/search?q=how%20to%20pivot%20without%20aggregation%20SQL%20Server)" gives good results too.

Comment: I must admit, the question isn't "too broad" but if it is reopened, I would likely choose to "hammer it" of at least one duplicate candidate.